how to run laravel on ubuntu automatically
I dont want to use php artisan serve, I want to open a laravel project on navigator using "http://localhost/mylaravelproject". What I have to do to configure Apache2 to do it?

Create a symbolic link: ln -s path/to/mylaravelproject /var/www/html/mylaravelproject.
